# parseo de variables de un objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, parsear

recurro a quien me pueda ayudar

Tengo un pagina que recbo de una consulta la siguiente respuesta, que en la tabla de la base de datos, cada variable es una columna y interpreta bien la funcion para mostra los resultados en el cliente.
asi lo copie de la consola

```
    [{"Id":"1","Id_empresa":"1","plan":"supeior"},{"Id":"2","Id_empresa":"1","plan":"medio"}]
```

Ahora cree otra consulta para los precios, tengo otra tabla donde cada columna tiene un precio de cada uno de estos planes y me los devuelve en un array de objetos, porque devuelva los reslutados de dos cunsultas simultaneas que luego las sumo usando Objet reduce y lo imprimo en la consola y se ve asi.

```
  { Plan_medio: 7924, Plan_superior: 11016 }
```

En principio quisiera usar con esas dos variables. y dejar de usar el anterior.
Quisiera que cada vez que itera usar de las variable, el nombre(ej:Plan_medio) y el precio (ej:7924)

Ahora lo tengo asi

```
   for ( j in planes ) {

     resHTML = '<div> PLAN '+ planes[j]['plan_nombre'] + '</div>'
             + '<div> Propiedad:'+ planes[j]['caracteristica_1'] + '</div>'
 Asi lo hice ahora

   for ( j in precio ) {
      resHTML = '<div>' + [j] + precio[j] + '</div>'
              + '<div> Propiedad: '+  + '</div>'
```

para  obtener algo similar.
Lo que haría luego sería que itere toda la información. Por ahora me vale reemplazar el de las caracteristicas que tengo y que quede solo el precio.

esa es la consulta.

Gracias por su interes en la consulta.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy difícil de entender. Por favor revisa la redacción y de paso agrega lo que has intentado mediante un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Diria que necesitamos ver lo que estas iterando ahora para poderte ayudar, es decir, su código, sino poco podremos ayudarte con tan solo sus resultados.

Comment: Hola , gracias, lo tengo iterando sin el precio. Ahora ya tengo separado el precio.